# Passing arguments to .NET-defined commands

Tags: .net, vb.net, command, autocad

I need to write a command on the command line on Autocad 2000i and I want autocad to prompt for a parameter. Then my vb.net program will act based on the recieved parameter.

Basically I guess my solution is all here: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/09/passing_argumen.html

Problem is, I cant find the reference to the Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput namespace being used in there.

What am I missing here? Did EditorInput not exist in Autocad 2000i yet?

---

Thanks a lot for your answer.

I have a vb.net project which adds a toolbar to autocad. 
I want to let the user change the selected value of a combo in my toolbar, by writing a commnad and a parameter.

How can I use your method in my project? 
Do I put the dvb file in my project? 
Can the vba file be integrated in my vb.net project?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the ObjectARX SDK yet?

Comment: .NET did not yet exist in the year 2000.

Comment: Yeah it did not exist, but my program which is written in vb.net uses the autocad api and has a toolbar for autocad. So I do have a back and forth between my vb.net program and autocad 2000i.

Answer (score 2):

.Net API did not exist for AutoCAD back in 2000. Things were done through LISP or VBA or a combination of both. Here is a brief explanation of things to do.

**the VBA-Only Way:**

Open Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor (alt + F11)

Type your code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String
str = InputBox("Enter radius:")

MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Type `"-vbarun"` in command prompt(without quotes)

Type `"Thisdrawing.Test"` (modulename.functionname)

**the VBA + Lisp Way -(my preferred method)**

Type your code in the editor as mentioned above.
Save your vba file (.dvb format)..suppose it is in `D:\Macros` folder with the name `MyDvb.dvb.`

Create a new Lisp File(open a notepad and type the code below and save as .lsp extension)
This lisp file will be used to call all the VBA macros.

```
(defun c:testcommand()
  (command "vbarun" "D:/Macros/MyDvb.DVB!ThisDrawing.Test")
)
```

now load this lisp for one time by typing `"ap"` at the command prompt. This helps us to keep the commands available for the session.

Type `"testcommand"` and you will see your code executed

Answer (score 1):

Here is how its done using .NET C#

// Ask the user to select a folder

```
        PromptResult res = ed.GetString("\nEnter the path of the folder: ");

        if (res.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(res.StringResult, "*.dwg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }
```

Let me know if you have any questions.