# How to send a parameter when calling AUTOCAD command programatically using AUTO CAD SDK

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I have a custom exe which references a DLL with necessary AUTO CAD dll's. I am using AUTO CAD SDK. I am able to call/execute commands using this SDK. I am trying to figure out on how to pass a parameter to a command method.

```
// Get the active document
AcadDocument acDocComObj;
acDocComObj = acApp.ActiveDocument;

// Optionally, load your assembly and start your command or if your assembly
// is demandloaded, simply start the command of your in-process assembly.
acDocComObj.SendCommand("(command " + (char)34 + "NETLOAD" + (char)34 + " " +
                         (char)34 + @"C:/wood_plc/TAD Program/TAD Indexer Service/Dev/Tad.Indexer.CadCommands/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/Tad.Indexer.CadCommands.dll" + (char)34 + ") ");
acDocComObj.SendCommand("TEST " + "custom parameter" + "\n");
```

Comment: So which part of the code above is not working for you?

Comment: I need to pass the parameter and retrieve it. It does not let me pass it and no errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to .NET-defined commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726660/passing-arguments-to-net-defined-commands)

Comment: What command do You pass? and what do You want to retrieve?